# What is the specific issue with this function in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

int length(int b[]) {
    return sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
}
int main(void) {
    int a[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4 , 5};
    printf("%d\n", length(a));
}
```

I've played around with this a bit and just wondering why it doesn't print the length of the array `a`. I know other ways to print the length, but I'm just wondering what the specific issue of this block of code is.

Comment: `sizeof(b)` is the size of a pointer as with parameter `int b[]`, `b` is a _pointer_.  Was that intended?

Comment: [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) has several explanations of why you can't use `sizeof` to determine the array size once it has decayed to a pointer.